# rstudio like repl for spark-shell

Tags: shell, apache-spark, read-eval-print-loop

I am looking for an interactive way to work with the `spark-shell` that would resemble rstudio.
My use is simple - I want to write code in the editor and execute line-by-line in the terminal of spark shell.
I have tried Jupyter notebooks and Zeppelin, but they seem to not yet be as ready as the Python backends.
Currently I cut and paste every time, but that becomes tiring after a short while.
Google searches haven't come up with anything I found useful.

Comment: Instead of writing in editor, why don't you write the code directly in spark-shell. Are you expecting suggestions of methods from a class in editor..?

Comment: I want my code to be reusable and to be saved to file, later to be run as a whole script.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346776/how-to-run-scala-script-using-spark-submit-similarly-to-python-script/44347237#44347237 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jupyter notebook, But you need respective kernel to be installed and configured to Jupyter.
[All available kernels for Jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels)

As you said spark-shell, I assume you are writing scala code.
Available kernels for scala are : [sparkmagic](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic) and [Jupyter-scala](https://github.com/alexarchambault/jupyter-scala) 
As of now Jupyter will allow you to download the script as a file with .py extension
Changing its extension and compiling will be an overhead(even though it can reduce your work to some extent)

Comment: I have tries toree and and SparkNotebook.
It seems as if notebooks are currently not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There two options:

1. **Using Scala Worksheets in Intellij IDEA**. It can simultaneously display the result as you type.There is no need to copy paste the code every time. Refer to this question to set it up: [How to setup Intellij 14 Scala Worksheet to run Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189206/how-to-setup-intellij-14-scala-worksheet-to-run-spark)
2. **Build your own environment by tweaking Atom text editor**. 
   There are various plugins in atom to include a terminal along with code editor. Install one of them and open spark REPL in the terminal. If you prefer, you can add a shortcut to run the selected code in the REPL from editor(like ctrl+enter in Rstudio) Refer: https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus